# How can I get the 'friendly' text for product status and visibility attributes?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

How can I get the friendly text for a products status and visibility options. for example, 'Enabled' or 'Disabled' rather the 1 or 2, and similarly for visibility 'Not Visible Individually', 'Catalog, Search' etc rather than 1,2,3 or 4?

I'm guessing there is a function somewhere that can take `$product->getStatus` and return the text value? and a similar one for visibility?

I'm just playing about getting used to magento trying to build a simple list:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection();

foreach ( $products as $product ) { 
  echo $product->getSku();
  echo $product->getStatus();
  echo $product->getVisibility();
}
```

but would like status and visibility to appear as they do in the admin pages rather than the numeric values.

EDIT: With the help of Mufaddal's answer, my final solution was;

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('visibility')
    ->addAttributeToSort('sku', 'asc');

foreach( $products as $product ){
    echo 'SKU: ' .$product->getSku() . '<br/>';
    echo 'Visibility: ' . $product->getResource()->getAttribute('visibility')->getFrontend()->getValue($product); . '<br/>';
    echo 'Status: ' . $product->getResource()->getAttribute('status')->getFrontend()->getValue($product); . '<br/>';
}
```

I needed to either `->addAttributeToSelect('*')` or specify each attribute in the select before the getResource calls would work e.g. `$product->getResource()->getAttribute('status')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
$products ->getResource()->getAttribute('status')->getFrontend()->getValue($products );
```

this is for status attribute.

Comment: Hi Mufaddal, using either:

`$products->getResource()->getAttribute('status')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);`

or

`$product->getResource()->getAttribute('status')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);`

I always get **No** returned as the result?

Comment: Where are you display this message?

Comment: I figured it out.. ->getCollection doesn't include the status and visibility values by default, I needed to either use `->addAttributeToSelect('sku')` or specify them individually e.g. `->addAttributeToSelect('status')` then either options tried before will work. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `addAttributeToSelect('*')` for all attribute

Answer (score 2):

You can also try:

```
$product->getAttributeText('status')
```

Which will work in some cases and not in others, but where it does work it is shorter and simpler than going through the resource.